# Why type argument cannot be inferred from usage if type argument constraint specifies the type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've created an extension method which is supposed to provide table header text for a table containing a collection of items of type `IList<T>`. Though, the compiler says that TModel cannot be inferred from usage, however, for me it is obvious if the type argument constraint says that `TListModel` is an `IList<TModel>`, then `TModel` could indeed be inferred.

```
public static MvcHtmlString HeaderFor<TListModel, TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TListModel> listViewModel, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) 
    where TListModel : IList<TModel>
```

`TListModel` is say `List<Product>`, so `TModel` is `Product`, and as such, I'd like to use the HtmlHelper like this:

```
<th scope="col" class="azonosito">
     @Html.HeaderFor(x => x.Price)
</th>
```

I now have to use it like this, which is so awkward:

```
<th scope="col" class="azonosito">
     @Html.HeaderFor((Product x) => x.Price)
</th>
```

Comment: Would it work for you to skip the TListModel type parameter completely and define the method like this: `HeaderFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<IList<Model>> listViewModel, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)`?

Comment: No, I've already tried. It says that no extension method exists accepting a first argument of type `HtmlHelper<PagedList<Product>>`.

Comment: Eric Lippert has done a number of blog posts in the past about how type inference and lambdas can be problematic because you're essentially trying to do type inference in two directions at once. I suspect that this will be somewhat related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a request previously made to the C# language team: [REQUEST: Pattern matching/better type inferencing with generics. #5023](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5023#issuecomment-170154313). However, note the linked comment, this introduces breaking changes, so is not currently implemented. See also https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11242 .

The problem is that the compiler is not able to infer the type of `TListModel` can only be `IList<TModel>`. It doesn't understand there is a connection between the members of the list (`IList<TModel>`), and the container (`TListModel`).

There are several ways to handle this. One, as you discovered, is explicitly supplying the type to the lambda, though you can also explicitly supply the type arguments: `@{Html.HeaderFor<IList<SomeModel>, SomeModel, int>(x => x.Price)}`.

For a practical solution, you can change the extension method definition. This change should provide the member type as part of the parameters to the extension method.

```
public static MvcHtmlString HeaderFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<IList<TModel>> listViewModel, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    return new MvcHtmlString("a");
}
```

This allows implicit type inference without compiler errors:

```
@model IList<SomeModel>
...
@Html.HeaderFor(x => x.Price)
```

further reading: [How can I return <TEnumerable, T> : where TEnumerable:IEnumerable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53620392/1462295) , see Jon Skeet's answer.